# How to query an array of FLOAT?

Tags: python, arrays, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table with a column with type `double precision[]` created like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column,  String,  ARRAY

mytablename= 'mytable'
class create_my_array_table(Base):
    __tablename__ = mytablename
    id = Column(String(3000, convert_unicode= False), primary_key= True)
    myarray= Column(ARRAY(Float), unique=False)
```

So if I have an array (Python list) **v**, this is how I'm trying to query it.

```
v = [0.0112, 0.235, 0.25...]
myDBtable= Table(mytablename, metadata, autoload = True, autoload_with = engine)
myquery =session.query(myDBtable).filter(myDBtable.c.vector ==v)
##test
for line in myquery:
    print(line)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: double precision[] = numeric[]

LINE 3: WHERE mytable.myarray= ARRAY[0.0112, 0.235...
                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: `SELECT '{1.5}'::FLOAT8[] = '{1.5}'::NUMERIC[]` in PG raises the same exception. The simple answer is to cast one of those fields to the other's type. If you can supply the values to PG in the same data type as is used in the table, so much the better.

Comment: How do I do that using SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Dunno, never used python or SQLAlchemy. I assume `myarray` is the  `float[]`, which means `v` is treated as `numeric[]`. In which case, can you explicitly state the type of `v` to be a float array rather than have the type be inferred?

Comment: I can't reproduce this (SQLA 1.4. psycopg2 2.9.1); the query value has type `DOUBLE PRECISION[]` using the code in the question.